# How to set the text of the field in flutter_typehead TypeAheadField widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, flutter-typeahead

I'm new to Dart and Flutter and I'm trying to use this module https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_typeahead to make a text field with autocomplete/"type ahead" functionality.

In the example they give, when the user selects one of the suggestions, they route the user to another view, but I don't want to do that. I'd just like to set the value of the input text to whatever the user selected.

Here's my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TypeAheadField(
              textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                autofocus: true,
                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()
                )
              ),
              suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                Completer<List<String>> completer = new Completer();
                completer.complete(<String>["cobalt", "copper"]);
                return completer.future;
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, suggestion){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(suggestion)
                );
              },
              onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I have no clue what to put inside of the `onSuggestionSelected`parameter function to achieve what I described.

Answer (score 16):

Ok, I found the solution which was actually on the same github link I provided, but since the example was not about the exact same component (`TypeAheadFormField` instead of `TypeAheadField`) and the example was only a piece of code that was lacking context, I had to look at the source to understand.

Here's how to proceed. This actually works both for `TypeAheadFormField` and `TypeAheadField`. You have to create a `TextEditingController` that you pass to the constructor of the `TypeAheadField` widget. Then you set the `text` property of that `TextEditingController` in your `onSuggestionSelected` callback method. The `TypeAheadField` widget will use that value to redraw itself, I guess that's how it works.

Here's the code that works:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final TextEditingController _typeAheadController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TypeAheadField(
              textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                autofocus: true,
                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()
                ),
                controller: this._typeAheadController
              ),
              suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                Completer<List<String>> completer = new Completer();
                completer.complete(<String>["cobalt", "copper"]);
                return completer.future;
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, suggestion){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(suggestion)
                );
              },
              onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                this._typeAheadController.text = suggestion;
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

define a local varible in in your state class of TextEditingController and name it `typeAheadController`,
then add this parameter to your typehead widget :

```
textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                            controller:  typeAheadController,
                            decoration: ....),
```

you can modify the field text in your callback (event) using

```
typeAheadController.text = "your text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in Decoration

```
TypeAheadField(
            debounceDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return CircularProgressIn
dicator(value: 10,);
            },
            keepSuggestionsOnSuggestionSelected: false,
            hideOnEmpty: true,
            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller: _typeAheadController,
              autofocus: false,
              style: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .labelMedium,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Your placeholder",
)
)
```